# How to make inputs not move on browser resizing?

Tags: php, css, html

I need your help to solve the following (I have search for similar situation and tried everything but I can´t get formatted as I want).

Situation:

I am creating a page in php, where I have a form to validate data inserted in our database. This form has various input checkbox and text, which have to be side by side. my problem is that when I resize my browser these checkbox and text end up unaligned.

I have tried position: absolute/relative/fixed, unsuccessfully as the result changes the format of the rest of my page.

can anyone shine me some light on how to solve this situation.

Thanks

ps. http://jsbin.com/jajamuda/1/ - http://codepad.org/il5M6RcJ

Comment: http://codepad.org/il5M6RcJ

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jajamuda/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the problem and solution you need it can be using the TABLE,

for example:

```
<table style="width:500px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:200px">
            Some text
        </td>
        <td style="width:300px">
            <input />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is it OK for you? also if you can provide jsfiddle I will change HTML for you.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid tables, http://codepad.org/il5M6RcJ

Comment: ok, you can use DIVs, with fixed widths style="width:200px", it also shold work for you. JSFiddle will be so helpful :)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jajamuda/1/

Comment: link dosn't work for me

Comment: Create something simple to show the issue.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/recunudi/1/edit

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsbin.com/recunudi/3/edit

Comment: @ Hayk Mantashyan- it seams to work perfectly, I´ll test it on my page

Comment: Nice to hear. If some problem feel free to comment. Also do not forget to accept answer as best one. :)

Answer (score -2):

For your code at http://codepad.org/il5M6RcJ

I think you are using width:100% for table tag, width:90% for td tags. That is creating problem. Instead try converting that percentage scale to pixel scale like 500px. then your textbox size won't change on changing the browser width.

I hope this will fix.

Comment: That is not what OP is talking about.

Comment: I also applied your suggestion

Comment: If your project is online you can send a link